# Use mySQL SUM() in where clause with over match by other field

Tags: mysql

I want to get the records having SUM of multiple fields over than the other field.
I tried the below method but not working. (paid_amount = second field to match value)

```
SELECT orders_id 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE cust_id = 20227 
HAVING SUM(freight+insurance+cost) OVER paid_amount
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be  you are just  looking for simple addition

```
SELECT orders_id 
FROM TABLE WHERE cust_id=20227  
    AND freight+insurance+cost > paid_amount
```